# How to get only date from multi string

Tags: php, date

I have sting like this:

```
"Last Updated Date is Feb 12, 2011"
```

I want to take only date value from this string in different format like

```
"Y-m-d"
```

Comment: @ToddSewell - a good duplicate candidate would also have to include basic string parsing and text-that-looks-like-a-date to true date conversion.

Answer (score 1):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) gives us the position upto `is` which 18, as we do not like to include `is` itself, we find its lenth using strlen. Using [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), we extract the data after the position from the word `is`. Since we don't want extra space, trim the result and Format it using [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$str =  "Last Updated Date is Feb 12, 2011";
$mydate = substr($str, strpos($str, 'is')+strlen('is'));
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y', trim($mydate));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

a short version for extracting the date:

```
substr($str, -12);
```